# How to markup addresses in my DB with Schema.org?

Tags: street-address, schema.org, microdata

I have a website with business listings and each of them has a full address. The problem is that the full address is only 1 row in DB, so I have no idea how to markup the addresses with Schema.org.

Example addresses:

> - 117, Northgate, Newark, NG24 1HJ
> - Unit 3, Canalside Industrial Park, Kinoulton Rd, Cropwell Bishop, Nottingham, NG12 3BE

Manual action is not an option, because I have thousands of listings.

So my question is: How can I add `itemprop="streetAddress"`, `itemprop="addressLocality"`, `itemprop="postalCode"` when the full address is placed in just 1 field?

In other words: how to separate postal code, locality and street from the address fields of my listings? Or can I add just one `itemprop` for the full address?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the whole thing in one `itemprop` won't work, I'm afraid.

If there's no way of fragmenting the address, you might consider using the [Data Highlighter tool in Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3106959). You use this to show Google where data is on a sample page and, assuming the data appears in the same way on each page of its type, Google can do the rest automatically.